# Build Linux kernel from source for ARM

Tags: arm, kernel

Where can I get from the Linux kernel 3.10 for arm7l?

I tried using the one for PC but when I compile it, it ask me the processor architecture and there is no ARM option.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure and build it for ARM architecture set environment variables or execute the following commands sequence.

1. ARCH=arm
2. CROSS_COMPILE=*your path to arm cross compile tools*/bin/arm-none-eabi-
3. make menuconfig

Instead of default x86 there will be ARM based architectures list in the menu.